# MySQL query slow besides using the index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery

I am running a query to find rows associated with others in the same table (specifically those which have the same `ddef` index, aka. all NOT NULL columns except `svar` are the same). The query is very slow and I don't understand why.

The table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `data_der_testing` (
        `def`       VARCHAR( 30 )     NOT NULL ,
        `cntry`     VARCHAR( 5 )      NOT NULL ,
        `var`       VARCHAR( 10 )     NOT NULL ,
        `type`      VARCHAR( 4 )      NOT NULL ,
        `svar`      VARCHAR( 5 )      NOT NULL ,
        `track`     INT ( 3 )         NOT NULL ,
        `year`      INT ( 5 )         NOT NULL ,
        `v1211`     TEXT,
        `v1212`     TEXT,
        `v1302`     TEXT,
        `v1304`     TEXT,
        `v1305`     TEXT,
        INDEX   ddef ( `cntry`, `var`, `type`, `track`, `year` ),
        UNIQUE  ( `def` ),
        UNIQUE  idb  ( `cntry`, `var`, `type`, `svar`, `track`, `year` )                        
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The data within the table consists of ~450k rows:

```
    `def`: a combination of all other "NOT NULL" columns, which makes it unique
    `cntry`: 34 country codes
    `var`: 86 variable codes
    `type`: 2 type codes
    `svar`: 3 sub-variable codes
    `track`: 6 codes
    `year`: 32 year codes (99, 1980...2010)
    `v...`: the variable value I want to check and update if needed
```

The output of SHOW INDEX:

```
    data_der    1   ddef    1   cntry   A   410                 BTREE   
    data_der    1   ddef    2   var     A   18871               BTREE   
    data_der    1   ddef    3   type    A   33388               BTREE   
    data_der    1   ddef    4   track   A   43404               BTREE   
    data_der    1   ddef    5   year    A   434048              BTREE
```

The query:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `data_der`
    WHERE `type`='str' && `svar` != '99' &&`v1305` = '-90' && ROW(`cntry`,`var`,`type`,`track`,`year`) IN
    (
         SELECT `cntry`,`var`,`type`,`track`,`year`
         FROM `data_der`
         WHERE `type` = 'str' && `svar` != '99' && `v1305` != '-90'
         GROUP BY `cntry`,`var`,`type`,`track`,`year`
    )
```

And it's EXPLAIN:

```
    1   PRIMARY             data_der    ALL                        434048   Using where
    2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  data_der    index           ddef    71      6   Using where
```

If you have any advise on how to make this question more useful to the general audience, please tell me so. I profit off other questions all the time and would be glad to contribute.

Best
Chonez

Comment: data_der = data_der_testing?

Comment: `v1305` is a TEXT column and mysql will have a hard time doing whatever with it unless you use some fulltext indices. Also, I'm pretty sure index merging doesn't work with TEXT columns so the engine will have to choose amongst your indices instead of combining them.

Comment: Usually, `IN( ....)` is particularly inefficient. This is very probably the case here as it is marked as `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`. You (or someone else) would have to rewrite that as a `JOIN` if possible...

Comment: The first problem is that the SQL optimalizer thinks it must run a table scan on your data. probably your indexes are not selective enough so mysql choose to run a complete table scan on table data_der. And it should really be a JOIN, IN is known tot make things very worse.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I posted a JOIN as the solution below, as suggested by you. And yes, `data_der` = `data_der_testing`, thx for noticing though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments (Thx, people!), I wrote the following JOIN which I will use to UPDATE:

```
    UPDATE `data_der`
    SET `v1305` = '-95'
    WHERE `def` IN
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT
                t1.`def`
            FROM `data_der` AS t1
            JOIN `data_der` AS t2
            ON (t1.`cntry`,t1.`var`,t1.`type`,t1.`track`,t1.`year`) = (t2.`cntry`,t2.`var`,t2.`type`,t2.`track`,t2.`year`)
            WHERE
                t1.`type`      = 'str'
                && t1.`svar`  != '99'
                && t1.`v1305`  = '-90'
                && t2.`v1305` != '-90'
        ) AS sub
    )
```

And the EXPLAIN of the subquery:

```
    1   SIMPLE  t1  ref idb,sdef,cntry,var,type,track,year,ddef type    14  const   65338   Using where
    1   SIMPLE  t2  ref idb,sdef,cntry,var,type,track,year,ddef ddef    71  impic.t1.cntry,impic.t1.var,const,impic.t1.track,impic.t1.year  1   Using where
```

So my INDEX `ddef` ( `cntry`, `var`, `type`, `track`, `year` ) is being used! Success! (You may ignore the other indices, I know that not all of them make sense...)

Just a bonus: Is there a shorter way to write the ON clause?